# C# CommandRow LinkButton add Javascript

Tags: c#, visual-web-developer

I am using the following C# to replace the texts 'Edit, Delete and Select' from the command row on GridViews.

I want to improve this by using a javascript 'confirm' dialogue to make the user double check before deleting a row. How can I do this from the LinkButton object?

```
private void commandIcons(GridViewRow row)
{
    if (row.Cells[0].Controls.Count == 5)
    {
        // we have a edit delete select control row type, replace text labels with icons
        LinkButton lbedit = (LinkButton)row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
        lbedit.Text = lbedit.Text == "Edit" ? "<img title=\"Edit\" class=\"icon\" src=\"Images/database_edit.png\" />" : lbedit.Text;

        LinkButton lbdelete = (LinkButton)row.Cells[0].Controls[2];
        lbdelete.Text = lbdelete.Text == "Delete" ? "<img title=\"Delete\" class=\"icon\" src=\"Images/delete.png\" />" : lbdelete.Text;

        LinkButton lbselect = (LinkButton)row.Cells[0].Controls[4];
        lbselect.Text = lbselect.Text == "Select" ? "<img title=\"Select\" class=\"icon\" src=\"Images/accept.png\" />" : lbselect.Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an "OnClientClick" to an linkbutton asking for confirmation. And performing an C# function afterwards using "OnClick". Hope it helps.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Deletebutton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" OnClientClick='return confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this?");'  OnClick="DeleteBrand">
```

Comment: Perfect, OnClientClick was exactly the property I was after!

Comment: Good to hear, using it in all the aspx pages myself. Glad I could help out